# How to conditionally render a loader spinner in react component?

Tags: reactjs

in one my react components I am using useContext to obtain data from the api, and I want to render a loader when it is fetching data from the api, so that the user does not see a blank white space while its loading.
How can I logically code a loader in my useEffect?

Thanks

```
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

 useEffect(() => {
  myContext.fetchCategories();
}, [myContext]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If myContext.fetchCategories returns a promise, you can do it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    myContext.fetchCategories().then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
    });
}, [myContext]);
```